# How do I center this <a> tag on this modal in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, bootstrap-modal

Hello thank you for looking at my question,

I'm trying so hard to center this link on a modal in bootstrap. I'm not using the grid system or rows. There's a BS carousel in the modal and I'm able to center the elements in that with `margin:0 auto;`

Heres a visualisation of where the links is, it stubbornly stays on the left of the modal.

[Click Here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Sfz.png)

The link should be right under the carousel indicators.

HTML snippet:

```
.
.
.
<div>
    <ol>
        <li> data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#home-price-guide-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

</div>

<a class="btn-center" href="#">Continue</a>

<div class="modal-footer">

</div>
.
.
.
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.btn - center {
    color: #95d63b;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;
}
```

Basically, how do I get `btn-center` to actually center.

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

1. `text-align:center;`
2. `.btn-center{
     color:#95d63b;
     position:absolute;
     transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
     left:50%;
   }`

you can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9pv1fLhv/)

Answer (score 0):

Amend your css above and add the below

```
Text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to make a tag with 100% and align center

```css
.center-link{

   text-align:center;

   width:100%;

   display:block; /* Displays an element as a block element (like <p>) */
}
```